# Is there a practical way of adding Webpack's generated stylesheets in Production

Tags: javascript, webpack, production, webpack-style-loader, extract-text-plugin

I'm building a normal App (JQuery, ES6, etc) with webpack and it's usual loaders. I came across the following situation:

- In development, I wish to use the [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader), to have my css in an inline tag.
- In production, I want to have a minified-css-bundle-file (dam, what a word), that I can cache later on and avoid [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). I'm using the well known [Extract Text Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) for that purpose.

The problem is, when I am in production I will need to add a 
`<link href="some-bundle.css" />` to my `index.html`. OK. But by doing this, back in development I would get a 404 every time, since my css is not coming from any external source (It comes from JS and it's inline thing).
And if I don't add the link tag, i'm never getting the compiled stylesheet.

So, how do you do this? Is there any loader to auto add the `<link>` in production? Or you just manually add It later on?

Thanks, []s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to generate index.html files based on your Webpack build (dev/prod). One would include the `link` tag, another would not.